# Remove attribute from FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I want to test that my Model will not let create an instance if one attribute is missing, so I have tried this:

```
 test "should not save without a url" do
    attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:page).delete(:url)
    page = Page.new(attrs)
    assert !page.save
 end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :page do
    url 'http://testpage.com'
    background 'rgb(255,255,255)'  
  end
end
```

However, I am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method stringify_keys' for "http://testpage.com":String`

What am I missing here? Or what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you want to take a look at the method [except](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except). The [delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete) method will return the value of the delete key, not the modified Hash.

So, you want this:

```
attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:page).except(:url)
```